# Adding a requirement for one date field to be greater than another

Tags: mysql

Example: I have 2 date/time fields in a table, `delivery_date` and `quote date`. `delivery_date` should always have a greater value (later in the calendar) than `quote_date`.

Is such a requirement enforceable in the schema for the table? That is, if I try to add a new row with a `delivery_date` before a `quote_date`, it will reject the change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use a [CHECK constraint](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-check-constraints.html) for this, for example:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CHECK (delivery_date > quote_date);
```

Assuming `delivery_date` and `quote_date` are defined as the MySQL `DATE` type or another temporal type (i.e. not strings).

CHECK constraints require MySQL 8.0.16 or later. If you must implement this on an older version of MySQL, you would have to write triggers before INSERT and before UPDATE, and use [SIGNAL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html) to abort the change if it doesn't pass your intended constraint.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of work-aroundy answer, but a possible way to go nonetheless

In my projects I store dates as `int unsigned` timestamps, so this questions immediately makes me think of taking an advantage of having an unsigned field.

If it's possible to modify the table, how about this schema:

| Quote date (timestamp) | Wait time (in seconds/10) |
| --- | --- |
| 1648771000 | 1080 |

<sub>In this example, quote date has a timestamp of 1648771000 (March 31, '22, 23:56:40), and the parcel is delivered in 1080 * 10 = 10800 seconds (that's 3 hours).</sub>

#### What for?

This way of storing data has a couple of benefits

1. No need for a check: since **wait time** is unsigned, neither insert nor update would allow for a negative value
2. **20% space saved:** a `date` occupies 5 bytes, that 10 for two of them. `int unsigned` occupies 4 bytes, that's 8 for two of them.
3. **Even more space saved** if we use `mediumint unsigned` for wait time and store data with precision to seconds, although won't allow wait time greater than 194 days (16777213 max value). **BUT** if we store wait time as `seconds / 10` (as per my table above), that's already 1940 days max. `mediumint unsigned` occupies 3 bytes, that would be 7 bytes in total (-30% compared to using `date`)

It's still easy to manage data in this schema - **delivery date** would be **quote date + wait time**